# Searching through a ManyToManyField in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have a model that contains a ManyToManyField. It looks like this..

```
applicable_events = models.ManyToManyField(Event)
```

I am trying to basically search using something like this:

```
if 'Video' in prop.applicable_events.all():
    print("here")
```

But it isn't fully working as I expected. I want it to search that applicable_event (which is another model). The applicable_event model contains a field named 'name' which I am trying to search against.

If I do something like this

```
print(prop.applicable_events.all().filter(name=cur_event))
```

It prints

```
<QuerySet [<Event: Video Sign In Started>]>
```

So basically I am trying to find out if the string 'Video' is contained in that.

Comment: What is `Event`? Can you share the relevant parts? A string like '`Video'` can not be an element of the collection of `Event`s.

Comment: Event is another model. Properties can apply to many events. Many events can apply to a test. I get the event name as a string. Then I search through the property to see if it applies to that event. But I am trying to do as a string. I added more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search if such event exists with:

```
if prop.applicable_events.filter(name__icontains='Video').exists():
    # …
    pass
```

or if you want an *exact* name match:

```
if prop.applicable_events.filter(name='Video').exists():
    # …
    pass
```

The reason `'Video'` in `prop.applicable_events.all()` does not work is because that is a `QuerySet` (a collection) of *`Event`s*, a string like `'Video'` is not the same as an `Event` with that `name`, and definitely not if `'Video'` is a substring of the `name`.